# Adding numerical value to node in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I define a node `Q` in TikZ:

`\node (Q) at (1,1) {};`

Now I want to draw a line to the point (2,2) by doing something like `(Q) + (1,1)`. Doing that I got an error. What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: \draw (Q)--++(1,1);

Comment: In addition, the `calc` library allows you to do more complex coordinate calculations.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you! What do I do in the following case:  `\node (N) at (1,1)+(0,1) {};`?

Comment: You could do `\node (N) at (1+0, 1+1) {};`. To add coordinates, not their components, look at the `calc` library, as @marmot mentioned. Add `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` to the preamble, and then use `\node (N) at ($(1,1) + (0,1)$);`

Comment: @Samuel `\path (1,1) +(0,1) node (N) {A};`